# How to move to another page onclick and still maintain the principle of the SPA

Tags: angular, typescript, single-page-application

In the Angular Project, I defined the main component to display data about companies in the table.

Below the table a button when a button is clicked is moved to a page with inputs to add a new company.
After filling in the fields click Submit and the new company is added to the DB.

Problem: Stay on the same page and do not see if the new company has been added to the DB.
How to move the user back to the main componette while maintaining the SPA principle?

```
public addCompany(newCompanyName:String, newCompanyPassword:String, newCompanyEmail:String ){
    let newP:any ={
      "name": newCompanyName,
      "password": newCompanyPassword,
      "email": newCompanyEmail,
      "coupons": []
      }

     this.myHttpClient.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/couponsystem/admin/insertCompany", newP).subscribe(
       (res)=>{
         console.log("new company");
         // How to redirect to adminComponent ?
        },
       (err)=>{console.log(err)}
     ); 
  }
```

I use angular routes:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { AddCompanyComponent } from './add-company/add-company.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{path:"login", component:LoginComponent},
{path:"admin", component:AdminComponent},
{path:"addCompany", component:AddCompanyComponent}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Want to switch from addCompany to Admin from addCompany.

**The addCompany function is not activated as soon as the button is pressed, but another function is activated (found in the addCmpany's TS) and runs addCompany (after checking that the fields are not null)**

the error message :

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/couponsystem/admin/insertCompany", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "A new customer was inserted"}
headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: ƒ ()
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/couponsystem/admin/insertCompany"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/couponsystem/admin/insertCompany"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Comment: are you using angular routing?

Comment: Angular routing ?`router.navigateByUrl('/path')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach `this.router.navigate(["/anotherComponent"])`.

import

```js
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
```

then

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {}

public addCompany(newCompanyName:String, newCompanyPassword:String, newCompanyEmail:String ){
    let newP:any ={
      "name": newCompanyName,
      "password": newCompanyPassword,
      "email": newCompanyEmail,
      "coupons": []
      }

     this.myHttpClient.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/couponsystem/admin/insertCompany", newP).subscribe(
       (res)=>{
         console.log("new company");
         this.router.navigate(["/admin"]);
        },
       (err)=>{console.log(err)}
     ); 
  }
```

Comment: I tried it and it did not matter.
The addCompany function is not activated as soon as the button is pressed, but another function is activated (found in the addCmpany's TS) and runs addCompany (after checking that the fields are not null)

Comment: are you getting the `console.log("new company")` output?

Comment: No, I'm getting the error. But when I come back to the table and do a refresher I see the new company ...

Comment: Can you create a quick stackblitz for this scenario? would help to solve this faster.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not know what stackblitz is ..
I will add the error message to the question content

Comment: I am unable to understand the flow. I have created a  [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5rkl3), you can just edit there and put your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because your request object doesn't fit with the expected of your DB, please try:

```
....
this.myHttpClient.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/couponsystem/admin/insertCompany", JSON.stringify(newP)).subscribe(
.....
```

Then when you get the correct response:

```
 (res)=>{
     console.log("new company");
     this.router.navigate(["/admin"]);
    }
```

I suggest you make an atomic test, try to navigate to other page without make the request.

Comment: I tried it and I'm still getting a different but different error:
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/couponsystem/admin/insertCompany: 415 Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: Did you try to just `this.router.navigate(["/admin"]);` without any request?